# String matching between 2 dataframe

Tags: python

Learning Python here, and any help on this is much appreciated.
My problem scenario is, there are 2 dataframes **A** and **B** contains a column(Name and Flag) list of Names.

```
ExDF = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['Smith','John, Alex','Peter Lin','Carl Marx','Abhraham Moray','Calvin Klein'], 'Flag':['False','False','False','False','False','False']})

SnDF = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['Adam K ','John Smith','Peter Lin','Carl Josh','Abhraham Moray','Tim Klein'], 'Flag':['False','False','False','False','False','False']})
```

The initial value of Flag is False.

**Point 1:** I need to flip the names in both dataframe ie. Adam Smith to Smith Adam and save the flip names in another new column in the both dataframes.
      - This part is done.

**Point 2:** Then both the Original name and flip names of **A dataframe** should get check in **B dataframe** original names and flip names. If it found the the flag column in both the dataframe should get update by True.

I wrote the code but it checks one on one row to both dataframe like `A[0]` to `B[0]`, `A[1]` to `B[1]`, but i need to check `A[0]` record to all the records of B dataframe.

Pls help me on this!!

The code which tried is below:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

ExDF_swap = ExDF["Swap"] = ExDF["Name"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(reversed(x.split()))) 
SnDF_swap = SnDF["Swap"] = SnDF["Name"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(reversed(x.split()))) 
ExDF_swap =  pd.DataFrame(ExDF_swap)
SnDF_swap =  pd.DataFrame(SnDF_swap)

vect = CountVectorizer()
X = vect.fit_transform(ExDF_swap.Name)
Y = vect.transform(SnDF_swap.Name)

res = np.ravel(np.any((X.dot(Y.T) > 1).todense(), axis=1))
pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=vect.get_feature_names())
pd.DataFrame(Y.toarray(), columns=vect.get_feature_names())

ExDF["Flag"] = np.ravel(np.any((X.dot(Y.T) > 1).todense(), axis=1))
SnDF["Flag"] = np.ravel(np.any((X.dot(Y.T) > 1).todense(), axis=1))
```

Comment: Please post how your dataframes look like after point 1 as you said that this is done and show the code how you tried to solve point 2

Comment: @SpghttCd FYI i attached the code above

Answer (score 0):

You could try `isin()` - of pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

ExDF = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['Smith','John, Alex','Peter Lin','Carl Marx','Abhraham Moray','Calvin Klein'], 'Flag':['False','False','False','False','False','False']})
SnDF = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['Adam K ','John Smith','Peter Lin','Carl Josh','Abhraham Moray','Tim Klein'], 'Flag':['False','False','False','False','False','False']})

print(ExDF)
print(SnDF)

ExDF["Swap"] = ExDF["Name"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(reversed(x.split())))
SnDF["Swap"] = SnDF["Name"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(reversed(x.split())))

print(ExDF)
print(SnDF)

ExDF['Flag'] = ExDF.Name.isin(SnDF.Name)
SnDF['Flag'] = SnDF.Name.isin(ExDF.Name)

print(ExDF)
print(SnDF)
```